# Looking for example Windows Phone 8 app that has registered a URI protocol with Windows Marketplace

Tags: uri, protocols, windows-phone-8, marketplace

Can anyone give me an example of a Windows Phone 8 app that has registered a URI protocol with Windows Marketplace?

i.e. the developer has followed "Registering for a URI association" in [these docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_URIassociations).

I've tried the obligatory `skype:myname` but Marketplace tells me no apps have registered themselves as supporting that protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Michelin Guide](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/store/app/michelin-guide/8f911ddb-a5c3-4e4a-aaea-cce3e0aabf11) has registered the `michelin:` protocol.

e.g. `michelin://Datasheet/?id=70972`

---

Nokia Music has registered the `nokia-music:` protocol.

e.g. `nokia-music://play/artist/?artist=deadmau5`

Comment: May be you know about some public database that contains info about apps with uri mappings ?